# logstash mysql error Data truncated for column at row 1

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

i am trying to setup logstash using jdbc mysql driver to index data in elasticsearch.  I keep getting  this error

```
[logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][pipeline_1] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Data truncated for column '_prim' at row 1>}
```

The mysql QUERY IS working fine in mysql workebnch!

Here is the logstash pipeline config file

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER_JAR_LOCATION}"
        jdbc_driver_class => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_DRIVER}"
        jdbc_connection_string => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_URL}"
        jdbc_user => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_USERNAME}"
        jdbc_password => "${LOGSTASH_JDBC_PASSWORD}"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
        statement => "
          SELECT
            t1.prim, t1.title, t1.description, tokeep
          FROM
            (
              SELECT 
                  a.prim, a.title, a.description
              FROM
                  b
                  inner join a on a.prim=b.prim
              GROUP BY
                  b.courseid
            ) t1

          LIMIT 1000
        "
    }
}
filter {
  if [tokeep] == 1 {
    mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][action]" => "index" } }
  }
  if [tokeep] == 0 {
    mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][action]" => "delete" } }
  }  
  mutate { 
    copy => { "prim" => "[@metadata][_id]" } 
  }
}

output {
  # stdout {codec => rubydebug}
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["${LOGSTASH_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}"]
    sniffing => true
    action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
    index => "my_idx"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    doc_as_upsert => true
  }
}
```

prim -> varchar(36), title -> varchar(1000), description -> text

Please help

Comment: ` copy => { "prim" => "[@metadata][_id]" } ` in here, not sure `_id`being a restricted field name. can you try using just `id` or something else?

Comment: No putting anything in the metadata field  should not matter. However, tried that but still same issue. Thanks